# Prove, that for every pair $(a,b)$ there is another pair $(u,v)$ so that $a\cdot v = b \cdot u$. $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\forall (a,b) a,b\in \mathbb{Z}^* \exists (u,v) u,v \in \mathbb{Z}^*:a\cdot v = b\cdot u$ $ \land  gcd(u,v) =1 $
>
> So basically I have to prove, that for every pair $(a,b)$ there is another pair $(u,v)$ so that $a\cdot v = b \cdot u$.I thought about proving the logic opposite, using Euclids algorithm's and using equivalence via modulo 1. But I can't think of anything specific. It seems to me there is an idea behind this how to find a special $(u,v)$ (with assistance of named algorithms).
>
> I hope you understand the problem and can provide hints or ideas how to approach this

Comment: Can you come up with *some* pair $u,v$ such that $a \cdot v = b \cdot u$, ignoring for the moment the additional requirement that $gcd(u,v)=1$?

Comment: $v = a^{-1}, u = b^{-1}$ because it will be 1, the neutral element of mulitplication. And if $a = b$, we can choose $(u,v) = (1,1)$, where $gcd(u,v) =  gcd(1,1) = 1$

Comment: Wouldn't the problem then be, that $a^{-1}$ falls out of $\mathbb{Z}^*$

Comment: Or, of course as Hagen von Eitzen suggests, $v = b, u = a$ now I need to make sure $v$ and $u$ have no common divisor by dividing by every common factor of $a$ and $b$ out of it

Comment: Hint: it's the same as computing a fraction $\, u/v = a/b\,$  in lowest terms. Surely you know how to do that, simply cancel their common factor $=\gcd(a,b).\ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try $u=a/d$, $v=b/d$ with $d=...$